# Source compiled OpenCV crashes on Google Colab without any error messages

Tags: python, c++, opencv, google-colaboratory

I am experimenting with compiling OpenCV on Google Colab from source. My script is as follows:

```
!pip3 uninstall -y opencv_python
!pip2 uninstall -y opencv_python
!apt purge --remove libopencv-dev
!apt-get install build-essential cmake unzip pkg-config libjpeg-dev libpng-dev libtiff-dev libavcodec-dev libavformat-dev libswscale-dev libv4l-dev libxvidcore-dev libx264-dev libx265-dev libgtk-3-dev libatlas-base-dev gfortran python3-dev checkinstall libeigen3-dev ccache
%cd /content
!mkdir opencv
%cd opencv
!wget https://github.com/opencv/opencv/archive/4.1.0.zip
!unzip -qq 4.1.0.zip
!git clone https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib.git 
%cd opencv-4.1.0
!mkdir build
%cd build
!cmake -DCPU_BASELINE_REQUIRE=SSE4_1,SSE4_2,AVX,FP16,AVX2,AVX512_SKX -DPYTHON_DEFAULT_EXECUTABLE=/usr/bin/python3 -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DOPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=/content/opencv/opencv_contrib/modules -DOPENCV_ENABLE_NONFREE=ON -DOPENCV_GENERATE_PKGCONFIG=ON -DENABLE_CCACHE=ON -DWITH_TBB=ON  -DWITH_EIGEN=ON -DWITH_CUDA=ON -DWITH_CUFFT=ON -DCUDA_ARCH_BIN=75 -DBUILD_opencv_cudacodec=OFF -DBUILD_DOCS=OFF -DBUILD_EXAMPLES=OFF -DBUILD_PERF_TESTS=OFF -DBUILD_TESTS=OFF -DBUILD_JAVA=OFF -DBUILD_opencv_js=OFF -DBUILD_opencv_ts=OFF ..
!make -j2
!make install
```

Everything compiles and installs successfully. I can check the OpenCV version and installed files using `pkg-config`. But the moment I try to use any OpenCV function in either Python or C++, it crashes.

This Python code makes the VM crash and restart:

```
import cv2
```

Any C++ code with OpenCV function in it exits without displaying any error messages:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "opencv2/highgui.hpp"
#include <opencv2/core/utility.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
   try
   {   
         waitKey(1);
   }
   catch( const cv::Exception& e )
   {
         cerr << "exception caught: " << e.what() << endl;
   }

    cout<<"hello"<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I have tried disabling CUDA, changing runtime type to `None` instead of `GPU` but nothing has resolved the issue. `ldd` prints every dependency correctly and `valgrind --leak-check=yes executable` gives [this output](https://pastebin.com/xrqPgkzf).

**Can someone detect the issue here?**

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know Colab supports C++ code.

Comment: @QuangHoang It's just like a normal Linux distro.

Comment: So you compile through Jupyter's `!` magic? also, the problem might be that the OS does not support `highgui` so `waitKey()` is never called. I'm not sure why it didn't raise an exception though.

Comment: @QuangHoang Yes, all through magic commands. The OS does support highgui but it's not just this function; any CV function kills the program.